# Show data in listview Android code

Tags: android

I have added data in sqlite now I want to show 
It in listview.I have shown it in text view but only one record show in text view.I want to show it in text view. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Post you code so we can help you easily

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data from sqlite to a cursor and iterate data, then add each rows to arraylist by creating custom item. Then create custom adapter and pass the arraylist to it. Then set adapter to tge listview

Comment: Thanks sangeet suresh.